# How to format f-strings with regex expressions?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, f-string

I have a few strings that were originally concatenated with plus signs and included regex strings. Here's an example:

```
"Level 4: " + re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", talents[1]) + "\n\n"
```

But, I've been meaning to use more proper formatting. I did some research on f-strings and I want to use them here. I tried it this way:

```
f'Level 4: {re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", talents[1])} \n\n'
```

However, my editor is barking at me about expression fragments having backslashes. Are f-strings not the right tool for the job in this case?

Edit:
As requested by @jwodder, here is the error I'm getting from Python (I'm on 3.6)

```
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
```

Comment: Who cares if your text editor is complaining?  Is *Python* complaining?

Comment: Just because you can use f-strings, doesn't mean you *must*.  With regex in particular is a case where it is probably more readable to separate the concerns of matching and formatting onto different lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot interpolate an expression with backslash in an f-string, and this is currently [a restriction by design](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences). You could separate this into two statements:

```
subst = re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", talents[1])
msg = f'Level 4: {subst} \n\n'
```

(Side note: There is currently a proposal ([PEP 536](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0536/)) to relax such restriction to make the original code work as expected, but it is not accepted or implemented yet.)

Comment: fantastic answer; saved!